# Get data from Webpage using dynamic browsing

Tags: c#

I want to browse a some other webpage dynamically, click on a link, go to next page fetch some data from that page and return to previous page. I am using c# console application . Can you please help me to find the solution regarding this.

I am able to get the webpage data using HttpWebRequest as text in stream reader but not able to goto next page or click the link. The Webpage is dynamic, sort of real estate site for rent advertisment. Any other better idea of doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a browser automation library, such as Watin (http://watin.org/)